How to calculate FF short/long term reversal for a portfolio?
As a newcomer to the finance world, I am working on replicating the Fama-French 5-factor model, along with Momentum and Short/Long-Term Reversal factors, to regress my portfolio's industry-adjusted returns against these factors. My goal is to determine whether these factors can explain my returns or if I can achieve significant alphas.
I have already successfully replicated the Fama-French 3-factor and 5-factor models, as described in their original papers (Fama & French, 1993; Fama & French, 2015). Similarly, I have implemented the Momentum factor (Carhart, 1997) and the HML factor based on current market equity, following the insights from the "Devil in HML Details" paper (Asness & Frazzini, 2013).
However, I have been unable to locate the original paper that introduces the Short/Long-Term Reversal effects, and consequently, I haven't been able to replicate this factor.
If possible, I would appreciate it if someone could point me to the original paper introducing the Short/Long-Term Reversal effect. Additionally, I would be grateful for guidance on how to calculate the monthly Short/Long-Term Reversal effect for my portfolio data.

I believe Short term reversal (1 month) was studied by Jegadeesh, Narasimhan, 1990, Evidence of predictable behavior of security returns, Journal of Finance 45, 881–898. Long Term Reversal (3 to 5 years) was identified by De Bondt, Werner, and Richard Thaler, 1985, Does the stock market overreact?, Journal of
Finance 40, 793–808. I am not sure if "short term/long term reversal" is just a combination of these two effects.

@nbbo2 that is exactly my issue. I am not sure who introduced and how to calculate it.

@Mostafa Bouzari : I don't know if it's related to what you're referring to but, in technical analysis, there's the MA cross-over where the short term MA goes above (below) the longer term MA. The cross-over then signals a buy or a sell. Again, I'm not certain that it's related to your short term/long term reversal but it's possible.

The answer lies in fama french's website for short-term and long-term reversal effects.
short-term:

We use six value-weight portfolios formed on size and prior (1-1)
returns to construct ST_Rev. The portfolios, which are formed monthly,
are the intersections of 2 portfolios formed on size (market equity,
ME) and 3 portfolios formed on prior (1-1) return. The monthly size
breakpoint is the median NYSE market equity. The monthly prior (1-1)
return breakpoints are the 30th and 70th NYSE percentiles.
ST_Rev is the average return on the two low prior return portfolios
minus the average return on the two high prior return portfolios,
ST_Rev =  1/2 (Small Low + Big Low)- 1/2(Small High + Big High).

Long-Term:

We use six value-weight portfolios formed on size and prior (13-60)
returns to construct LT_Rev. The portfolios, which are formed monthly,
are the intersections of 2 portfolios formed on size (market equity,
ME) and 3 portfolios formed on prior (13-60) return. The monthly size
breakpoint is the median NYSE market equity. The monthly prior (13-60)
return breakpoints are the 30th and 70th NYSE percentiles.
LT_Rev is the average return on the two low prior return portfolios
minus the average return on the two high prior return portfolios,
LT_Rev =    1/2 (Small Low + Big Low) - 1/2(Small High + Big High).

